# Angular/Breeze: How to define a zero-to-many relationship in Entity Framework code first?

Tags: entity-framework, angularjs, breeze

I'm working on an angular/breeze web app with EF code first, and run into a strange problem. Here is the code snippet:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

// DbContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasOptional(x => x.Address).WithMany(x => x.Persons).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);      
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Everything runs fine except one case: You can create a Person without specifying an address, however, once you select an address for the person, you can change to another one, but you can't remove it.

This is how I remove it in Angular select:

```
<option value=""></option>
```

This is the error I got when trying to reset the address:

```
{"The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Person_dbo.Address_AddressId\". The conflict occurred in database \"MyDb\", table \"dbo.Address\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

So, what's wrong?

UPDATE:
As I figured out, the problem seems to be on the client side. When an empty option is selected, it sets the AddressId to 0, instead of NULL. If I change it to NULL in debug mode, it would work. This is the complete select code:

```
<select ng-model="person.address" ng-options="g.name for g in addressList"><option value=""></option></select>
```

Now, the question is that how can I make it return its id as NULL instead of 0 in case an empty address is selected?

Comment: please add the code that handles the update process.

Comment: How do you remove the `Address`?

Comment: @Alex Choroshin, as said, I'm using Angularjs with Breeze. The update is handled by breeze automatically.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, the address can be removed separately without problem. Actually, this is just fake data to make the scenario easy to understand.

Comment: I don't know for sure (so posting as a comment), but I think the answer is "you can't" EF does not support `0..1 - *` relationships, only `1 - *` or `* - *` via a 3rd table. But things may have changed since I last checked.

Comment: I got some insight and updated my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you set up a plunker?

It seems to me that the `Person.addressId` should be flagged as nullable in the metadata (can you confirm?) and therefore Breeze should set `addressId` to `null` (not `0`) when you null the `Person.address`.

I have a feeling this may be an Angular issue involving your combobox binding option, `<option value=""></option>`. I'm not sure that is doing what you think it is doing when used in combination with `ng-options="g.name for g in addressList"`.

You might consider placing a "button"  ('x' for "clear") next to the combobox that, when clicked, sets `Person.address = null` or `Person.addressId = null`.

Comment: Over the weekend, I upgraded Breeze from 1.2 to 1.4 and EF from 5.0 to 6.1. Magically, the problem is resolved now. I can see from debugger that the id is set to null instead of 0 on selecting the empty option.